# How to remove slash in task name in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, task

I am trying to run an old Android project, but have errors in the build.gradle (:app) file.

```
ndk_projects.each { File file ->

//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
 task "copy $file" (dependsOn: "build $file", type:Copy) {
     from "$buildDir/tmplibs"
     into "$buildDir/libs"
 }


//noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
 task "build $file" (dependsOn: ["copy $OpenNI2_path",  "copy $OpenCL_path"], type:Exec) {
     workingDir file
     commandLine "${ndkDir}/ndk-build",
             "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=${buildDir}/intermediates/ndk"  ,
             "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=${file.absolutePath}/jni/Application.mk" ,
             "APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=${file.absolutePath}/jni/Android.mk",
             "NDK_LIBS_OUT=${buildDir}/tmplibs"
             environment NDK_MODULE_PATH: ndk_projects[0].absolutePath + "/jni" + ":" + OpenCL_path + "/obj/local/"
 }

}
```

The error says `task name must not contain any of the following characters: [/, \, :, <, >, ", ?, *, |].`. As it uses the file path as the task name, so I should change that. A simple fix can be to remove all the slashes in the pathes and use that as a task name. But, I have zero knowledge about Gradle syntax. Can someone tell me how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle uses Groovy, which is generally compatible with Java. Groovy has a `replaceAll` methods on String, which you can use here with a regex:

```
task "build ${file.path.replaceAll("[/\\\\:<>\"?*|]", ' ')}" (...) {
    // ...
}
```

You can replace fewer characters if you'd like, this replaces all invalid characters to a space.